# How to merge lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

For demonstrating purposes suppose I have the following.

```
j[-1, z_] := Cos[z];
j[1, z_] := Sin[z];
h[n_] := Table[j[(-1)^n, i π/2], {i, 5}];
```

What I want to do is simply combine the result I get from `h[1]` and `h[2]`

For `h[1]` the output is

```
{0, -1, 0, 1, 0}
```

While for `h[2]` the output is

```
{1, 0, -1, 0, 1}
```

I want to merge these two lists so I get

```
{0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1}
```

How  can I do it? Or is there perhaps an easier more elegant way to do it, like to tell my function `h[n_]` to do the case `n=1` and `n=2` straight away?

Comment: Do you mean to `Join` them?

Comment: I get for your example: `h[1]={0.707107, 0., -0.707107, -1., -0.707107}` and `h[2]={0.707107, 1., 0.707107, 0., -0.707107}`?

Comment: Yeah `Join` would have done it as well. @mrz Sorry it should have been `π/2` and not `π/4`.

Comment: `h[1]~Join~h[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Join` will do the trick:

```
j[-1, z_] := Cos[z];
j[1, z_] := Sin[z];
h[n_] := Table[j[(-1)^n, i π/2], {i, 5}];

Join[h[1], h[2]]

(* {0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey I figured it out. 
Writing the following does the trick

```
j[-1, z_] := Cos[z];
j[1, z_] := Sin[z];
h = Table[j[(-1)^n, i π/2], {i, 5}, {n, 2}]
```

Comment: To get the answer that you requested in the question, you need to change the order of summations and use `Flatten`, i.e., `h = Table[j[(-1)^n, i \[Pi]/2], {n, 2}, {i, 5}] // Flatten`

Answer (score 0):

```
j[-1, z_] := Cos[z];
j[1, z_] := Sin[z];
h = Table[j[(-1)^n, i π/2], {i, 5}, {n, 2}]

Flatten@{Take[h[[All, 1]]], Take[h[[All, 2]]]}

(* {0,-1,0,1,0,1,0,-1,0,1} *)
```